# KeyError: Timestamp when converting date in column to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert the date (type=datetime) of a complete column into a date to use in a condition later on. The following error keeps showing up:

> KeyError: Timestamp('2010-05-04 10:15:55')

Tried multiple things but I'm currently stuck with the code below.

```
for d in df.column:
    pd.to_datetime(df.column[d]).apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

Also, how do I format the column so I can use it in a statement as follows:

```
df = df[df.column > 2015-05-28]
```

Comment: try this, pd.to_datetime(df['your column'],errors='ignore') then inspect the dtype it should be a datetime, if so, just do df.loc[df.['your column'] > 'your-date' ]

Comment: you can also force non datetime values in your column into NaT (not a time value) by changing the argument from errors='ignore' into 'coerce'

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice! That's the solution!

Comment: happy to help : )

Answer (score 3):

Just adding an answer in case anyone else ends up here :

firstly, lets create a dataframe with some dates, change the dtype into a string and convert it back. the errors='ignore' argument will ignore any non date time values in your column, so if you had John Smith in row x it would remain, on the same vein, if you changed errors='coerce' it would change John Smith into NaT (not a time value)

```
# Create date range with frequency of a day
rng = pd.date_range(start='01/01/18', end ='01/01/19',freq='D')
#pass this into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : rng})
print(df.dtypes)
Date    datetime64[ns]
#okay lets case this into a str so we can convert it back
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)
Date    object
# now lets convert it back #
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='ignore')
print(df.dtypes)
Date    datetime64[ns]
# Okay lets slice the data frame for your desired date ##
print(df.loc[df.Date > '2018-12-29'))


 Date
363 2018-12-30
364 2018-12-31
365 2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer as provided by @Datanovice:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['your column'],errors='ignore')
```

then inspect the dtype it should be a datetime, if so, just do

```
df.loc[df.['your column'] > 'your-date' ]
```